# How do I detect focus on an InputText field in Android?

Tags: android

I know I MUST be a total idiot, but I don't see anything in the documentation that resembles an onFocus event handler for an InputText view in Android.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [View.OnFocusChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html) any use to you?

Comment: I KNEW I was an idiot... and you have verified my suspicions.

Comment: lol - don't feel so bad, I have a mental block about something obvious at least once a week...at my age though I can blame it on having a 'senior moment' :)